# No network connections in Windows 10 after attempted uninstall of Intel proset drivers

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, uninstall

So basically after attempting to uninstall Intel Wi-Fi proset drivers, the network adapters are not showing up. Even after reinstalling the same or newer drivers, the adapters aren't being recognized. The light for the wireless hardware isn't lighting up either, although booting up into another OS makes it work fine.

I've tried manually uninstalling the proset drivers, however, trying to uninstall the drivers in device manager doesn't work. It'll just keep showing the same drivers.

I've tried the Windows uninstall utility, reinstalling and uninstalling, and manual uninstall of the drivers. Nothings worked so far.

I'm trying to reset my pc at this point, but that's not working either haha.

Comment: Did you already try dropping back to a [System Restore point](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html) prior to when the problem occurred?

Comment: Yeah, for some reason all my restore points got deleted. Probably from using tweaking.com's fix windows utility, but I'm not really sure. But yeah, tried that.

Comment: Ok, so I've managed to remove the driver with the help of an app (driver talent), but now when installing the correct drivers (Intel proset wireless) - the drivers are still not being recognized by the adapter, and the drivers are not being installed.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Just to double-check, you ensured that the driver is compatible with Windows 10, it works with your version (either x86 or x64), and it will allegedly work with your specific device?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, they should work. The problem is that the last time I installed the proset app, it disabled my wireless adapter, so the obvious solution would be to reinstall the APP and reenable the adapter. However, for some reason, my recent installs of different versions I haven't been able to access the proset app.

Comment: Also, installing the newer versions of the driver still don't update the driver in device manager. The Dell (my laptop) drivers also don't work in win10x64 - it ends with the error of invalid data.

Comment: Perhaps check to see if Dell has a version of the proper device drivers for Windows 8 x64?  Those will often work on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Those are the ones I was trying. I managed to get the proset app back through a system restore but again uninstalling the drivers through device manager doesn't work, and newer drivers don't update the drivers. Would it be advisable to directly delete the drivers under the system32/drivers folder?

Comment: I wouldn't do that.  Manually removing anything from the System32 folder can potentially cause serious issues.  Based upon my experience, I think that the root cause of the "problem" is that the drivers are typically integrated with the Intel PROSet software.  As a result, removing *just* the device drivers probably isn't possible with that software installed.

Comment: Yeah, but I've already uninstalled the proset app, the drivers should go with them no? As of right now, even with the app installed, the drivers aren't updated, and the adapter isn't recognized, and unable to be turned on. With the app uninstalled, the same drivers remain and are unable to be uninstalled in device manager.

Comment: The entire scenario is very unusual, and a bit difficult to decipher remotely.  When you say that you *"managed to get the proset app back through a system restore"*, exactly what did you do?  You previously said that you didn't have any System Restore points to utilize.

Comment: Yeah, I used a restore point that was after my wireless was already f'ed up, and the app appeared in my taskbar. The main point is that my wireless adapter is currently disabled by the proset software, and I'm currently unable to completely delete the drivers or enable the adapter via the proset app. When I said I didn't have any restore points to use, I meant ones before my wireless stopped working.

Comment: To clarify, the problem first appeared when you attempted to remove your Intel PROSet software?  Prior to that, your Wi-Fi NIC was working properly?  Also, is this the same machine that had the problems with Windows BitLocker described in your other question/

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. And like I said before, it's absolutely the proset app, because I've had this problem before,  and again, I've tried booting into another OS and the adapter works fine.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, *why* were you trying to remove your Intel PROSet software?  That being said, I know that it sounds overly simplistic, but at a certain point in time you might need to seriously consider a full Windows wipe-and-reload.  Between the BitLocker issues and the mystery behind your Wi-Fi drivers, this particular OS build has encountered some extraordinary issues.

Comment: I'm not really sure, it was a while ago, but I think I wanted to switch to using the Windows service and forgot to switch to it in the app before uninstalling it. And yep, I've already been in the process of saving my important files and preparing for a clean install. I've been booting off an ubuntu USB drive in the mean time. Haven't really looked too far into the bitlocker problem yet, as it only locked one of the partitions of the USB I'm using and left my ubuntu partition untouched. So, a bit of luck I guess.